# Проверка на наличие элементов

Tags: c#, .net, linq

Всем привет.

Хочу проверить пришедший объект на "есть ли что-то внутри" , Empty как я понимаю. Могу ли я использовать эту форму (.Any())?

```
if (summaryViewResultSection.ReceivableAccountBalance.Items.Any() &&
                summaryViewResultSection.PayableAccountBalance.Items.Any())
            {
                var receivableBalanceTable = GetReceivableBalanceTable(summaryViewResultSection, worksheet, currency, currentRow, currentColumn);

                var payableBalanceTable = GetPayableBalanceTable(summaryViewResultSection, worksheet, currency, receivableBalanceTable.CurrentRow + 3, currentColumn);

                GetNetTotal(receivableBalanceTable, payableBalanceTable, worksheet, currency, currentColumn);
            }
            else
            {
                if (summaryViewResultSection.PayableAccountBalance.Items.Any())
                {
                    GetPayableBalanceTable(summaryViewResultSection, worksheet, currency, currentRow, currentColumn);
                }
                else
                {
                    GetReceivableBalanceTable(summaryViewResultSection, worksheet, currency, currentRow, currentColumn);
                }
            }
```

Прикрепляю объект который может приходить в Json

```
"payableAccountBalance": {
                "items": [],
                "total": 0.0
            },
```

Comment: А какого типа ваш объект-то?

Comment: Если коллекция (`IEnumerable<T>`), то да, можно.

Comment: У меня коллекция IEnumerable <T>

Comment: Понял, спасибо!

Answer (score 3):

Если коллекция имеет тип `IEnumerable<T>` или более конкретный тип, реализующий этот интерфейс (например, `IReadOnlyCollection<T>` или там `List<T>`), то проверять на наличие элементов вполне можно через `.Any()`.

---

Функция `Any` [проверяет](https://source.dot.net/#System.Linq/System/Linq/AnyAll.cs,8788153112b7ffd0), не поддерживает ли объект интерфейс, с помощью которого можно проверить количество элементов без потенциально медленного перечисления, и пользуется им.

Если вы хотите пожертвовать читабельностью ради минимального выигрыша в эффективности (например, ваш код — часть цикла, который должен быть очень быстрым), и вам известен точный тип коллекции, и эта коллекция поддерживает свойство `Count` (не LINQ-функцию `Count()`!), то можно заменить проверку на `collection.Count != 0`. Замена свойства `Count` на функцию `Count()` скорее всего сделает ваш код лишь *медленнее*.

Comment: Я понял, спасибо большое за подробный ответ. Просто чтобы убедиться, что я корректен, с текущим объектом (см json file) - any должно работать отлично, верно?
К сожалению, сейчас это недоступно для тестирования из моей ветки, поэтому приходится уточнять. 
Например, когда я получаю payableAccountBalance как в файле Json, в моих условиях выполнится только метод: GetReceivableBalanceTable. Верно?

Comment: @Кирилл: Ну если `PayableAccountBalance.Items` окажется пустым, то да, только `GetReceivableBalanceTable`.